# Reload data to current row in databinding from database - C#

Tags: c#, bindingsource

I have a bindingsource, and I want to add a button to the windows form to refresh just the current record (row) from the database to retrieve the values of the fields if they have been changed from other program or form.
I can refresh the whole bindingsource but I want to know if there is a way to refresh just the current row and show the new values at the form without closing it or without lose the position the user is watching.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: There are no way to reset only one row. But you could always keep in memory which row you're on before refreshing it and go back to it afterward (if it still exists).

Comment: What I have done is what Gabriel GM says (refresh the bindingsource and go to the record the user whas seeing), and when the data is filling and selecting the rememberd row, there is a blink where you can see briefly the first record and suddenly the remembered record, that is why I thought maybe I can reload just the current.